# Using ID in session to populate form fields in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I want a form I have created in CakePHP2 to display blank if no data is posted but to be populated with data from the model if the session key Person.id exists. Here's my code:

```
function about() {
    // Make session key for debug purposes
    $this->Session->write("Person.id",1);
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        debug("post");
    } else {
        debug("not post");
        // Use the value in the session Person.id to find the 
        // record in the Person model
        $this->params->data = $this->Person->findById($this->Session->read("Person.id"));
    }
}
```

Most of the above works. If I access the view without posting any data then the form is populated with the data from the `Person` model as expected.

However, if I post the form, I still get the debug message `not post` when I was expecting `post`.

If I comment out the line assigning data to `$this->params->data` then submitting the form gives me the correct debug message of `post` but I don't understand why this is happening.

If having `$this->params->data` populated means the same to Cake as a form post, then how am I suppose to check for a true, genuine form post?

**UPDATE:** If I change `if($this->request->is('post'))` to `if($this->request->data)` then it works exactly how I want it to....  but I still don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CakePHP2, when you create a form in the view with the FormHelper, it [automatically generates](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-forms) this field

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>
```

when you edit a record (meaning its primary key is set).

When you submit the form, this hidden field overrides the HTTP method and your request is not seen as a POST, but as a PUT. You could update your test like this:

```
if($this->request->is('put')) {
  ...
}
```

or to reflect the code that you obtain when you use `bake`

```
if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
  ...
}
```

If you want to see it yourself, just debug the request:

```
debug($this->request);
```

Then a bit out of topic, but if the key "Person.id" in your session is the logged in user, you probably use a custom mechanism to login/logout the users and it would probably be worth looking at the [AuthComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html).

Comment: a great explanation, thank you! The `Person.id` is actually the result of a query which searches the `Person` model for the `id` of a record based on the email address submitted. I'm using the above code as part of a multi-stage submission form. The data gets put into the database as each step is submitted but I wanted a way to pull the data back out into the form if the user decided to go back to one of the previous stages.